# Express error handling and process continuation

Tags: node.js, express

```
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(cookie_parser());
  app.use(session_manager());

  //Error handling expirement


  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log("After session manager!");
    return next();
  })

  app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.log(err.message);
    return next();
  });

  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.write("Hi");
    res.end();
  });
```

So the issue, i managed to figure out that error handler will call the next() only if i had something declared after the error handler.

It will not log After session manager, but if i move it beneath the error handler it will work just fine.

Back to the issue, i would like an error handler to handle the error and get back to running what it was running before i threw an error. i am aware that `throw new Error` will result in function interruption. i am more interested in running the next middleware in queue

How to get back to executing next function in middle ware list ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a bare bone thought that you can do this by creating multiple promises which are executed parallely and do a promise.all() which will promisify all at the same time, of these promises would be rejecting returning the error,which will be caught up by the non isolated catch

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve("after session manager");
var promise3 =Promise.resolve("Hi");
var promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
  reject(err)
}).catch(err=>{
throw new Error(err);
};

var finalResolver=Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
}).catch((err) =>{
 console.log(err);
});
app.use(finalResolver);
```

Comment: but how to run this in express middleware context ?

Comment: try this assign the promise.all to a variable and pass it to the app.use() as a middleware @AntonStafeyev

Comment: the middleware is already wrapped in promise, and it calls `next(err)` if it catches and error. so i got that covered. the question as how to get back to router at a specific point after calling error handler which express provides.

Comment: `const asyncMiddleware = fn => (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
};`